# How to add dynamic text entered by user to canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-edittext, android-styles

I am making an app in which a user enters some text and that text has to be displayed on a rectangle on an image(like a notes-stick on the image, it can be dragged on the image and also re-sized). I am very new to android and i really can't find a way to do so in android through books and google.
I have been designing apps using html, in html we could just style a text-box like we want and add it anywhere on the page. But here i am unable to configure the edit-text to do the same. But i am unable to make the edit-text like a notes-stick and to make it draggable and re-sizable dynamically.
I also tried drawing just a rectangle using canvas.drawrect() ... but how to add text to that dynamically is something which i am unable to figure out.
I am not asking for the entire code ..but please guys give me a head-start to the right direction so that i can try things out and try to figure out a way.. Right now i am badly stuck.
The image below shows how the notes-stick should look like...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it to be actually drawn on the canvas itself, using an EditText widget and having both it and your image in a RelativeLayout may be the way to go. You can set max height and width of the EditText, or have it wrap the height so it expands with the text, etc. Just make sure that the EditText widget gets added to the RelativeLayout after the image, so it is on top.

Comment: Thankx for answering... i tried using edit text.. but can it be draggable and re-sizable dynamically..

Comment: To my knowledge any dragging implementation is going to be pretty low level stuff, compared to clicking. Easiest approach (if using API level 11 or higher) would be to set the OnDragListener for the image or EditText and stuff around pulling in the DragEvents and feeding the X and Y information back to the position and size of the EditText widget. Maybe use the OnDraw method in the image to draw a handle on the corner outside the EditText, then drags need to start in this region? Either way, I'm pretty sure it's going to get messy quickly.

Comment: i want to drag the text note over the image and not the image.. can it be styled the way it looks in the above picture..

Comment: It could, but it would require a lot of fiddling with custom styles, fonts and drawables. Just a thought - another way this could be implemented is to manually draw the text during the OnDraw() method, but edit it in a separate EditText situated below the image. The code for tapping and dragging on the image and grabbing the coordinates can quickly get complicated though (likely too complicated for a short answer here)